# Android System app not able to create directories

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am developing an android app.In one of the modules I am creating a directory in the external storage to store files using the below code.Things work fine and I am able to create the directory.

```
    public class Main extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button btnCreateDir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createDir);
            btnCreateDir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        File pictureFileDir = getDir();

                        if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't create directory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"directory created/exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e4) {
                        e4.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }   
        private File getDir() {
            File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            return new File(sdDir, "GaPopupFile");
        }
    }
```

However, when I make this app as a system app(by signing with the system certificates and storing in system/app folder) I see that this same code when executed,returns 'Can't create directory' . How is this possible,what am I missing here ?

Comment: You might want to log the actual path attempted in both normal and system app cases.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : I did your suggested test case.Here is what I concluded.While installing the system app ,when I removed 'android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"' from the manifest,I saw that I was able to create the directory just as I was able to do in when the app was installed as a user app.What could be the reason? Is it that my so called 'system app' was actually not getting really installed as a system app?

Comment: There may not be an appropriate external storage directory for aid:system - iirc historically that user was prohibited from even touching the external storage as any process with a file handle open to the sdcard (originally used to implement it) is immediately killed if the sdcard is unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this permission in AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Read permission needed to read file in Android applications.
Write permission needed to write file in Android applications.

Comment: Yes, I have both those permissions in place.I got this resolved based on my comment above.